# How to detect android watch is worn or not on AW2.0

Tags: wear-os

Android wear 2.0 screen can be automatically locked right after it is taken off
and the heart rate app / watch face would not work when it is not worn.

I am wondering is there any way to get current wear worn state without starting a service to listen to wear activity?

I tried to get the heart rate sensor accuracy, but I don't think it is a good way because I can not always get the right result in this way immediately.

Is there any system or gms API to get a current worn state synchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On watches with an off-body sensor (which lock immediately when not worn), you can check for the existence of the wakeup sensor [TYPE_LOW_LATENCY_OFF_BODY_DETECT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_LOW_LATENCY_OFFBODY_DETECT). This is only a public API in O+, but you can just use the actual value for N MR1 and below.

```java
SensorManager sensorManager = 
    (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
boolean hasSensor = sensorManger.getDefaultSensor(34, true /* wakeup */) != null;
```

On watches without an off-body sensor (which don't lock immediately), your best bet is probably some sort of activity recognition, though there don't seem to be any public off-body activities that can be detected by Google APIs (see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#STILL)).

Comment: Thanks, but the off-body sensor check does not work on huawei watch2 with AW 2.0, the returned value shows the sensor(34) is always active whether or not the watch is worn.

Comment: But the watch do have the automatically lock feature

Comment: Do you have any code for this? If you register for sensor events it should return different values when on and off body

Comment: I made a mistake, after getting the sensor, I register a sensor listener, and the right on-body state is received immediately, thank you very much.

Comment: This is a one-shot sensor, I don't know why the requestTriggerSensor interface returns false, but registerListener works

Comment: @zhlicen Can you show the sensor listener code. I want to know how you are reading the state ?